# zend framework 2.3 acl - give permition to all actions in a controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have already googled and found some articles on how to allow access to all actions in a controller but none seems to be working in my app :(

I know from documentation that if I pass empty parameter(s) to $acl->allow or deny method it will set permitions "to all" so to speak. It is ok as i have $acl->deny() at the very top of my acl definition and my app is blocked - ok.

Then I go and ->allow(null, 'Contact') and all groups has access to this Contact module.
I am also ok with ->allow('guest', 'Auth', 'index:login') that allows only guest user to access login action of index controller in Auth module.

But now i want to allow all actions in registration controller (auth module) for "guest" role by calling something like ->allow('guest', 'Registration') but it throws me an error.

I believe when i pass "Registration" as a parameter it is looking for Registration module, while it is only a controller in Auth module. I tried to register resource as "Registration" (error). I have read somewhere to register controller as a resource like "MyModule/MyController",  it does not throw error, but redirects me to 404 that is a part of ->!isAllowed logic. It behaves the same when i do not declare this.

Question is how should i declare a resource do point a controller not a module, or generaly what is wrong with my code.

Below is my acl declaration and module map.

```
MyApp
    Application - module 
        Index - controller
    Contact
        Index
    Auth
        Index
        Registration
```

```
        $acl = new Acl();

        $acl->addRole(new Role('guest'))
            ->addRole(new Role('user'))
            ->addRole(new Role('admin'));

        $acl->addResource(new Resource('Application'))
            ->addResource(new Resource('Auth'))
            ->addResource(new Resource('Contact'));
        //how to declare Registration controller (auth module) as resource?? 

        $acl->deny();

        $acl->allow(null, 'Application')
            ->allow(null, 'Contact')
            ->allow('guest', 'Auth', 'index:login')
            ->allow('user', 'Auth', 'index:logout')
            ->allow('admin', 'Auth', 'index:logout');
        //how to allow access to group 'guest' to controller Registration??
```

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

There is a PR to add permissions check for controller actions in [ZfcRbac](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac)

Here is the [pull request](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac/pull/238)